# Using crypto-js to encrypt password and send form via ajax (and decrypt in java), I get : TypeError: Cannot read property 'words' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, encryption, cryptojs

I am trying to secure the password that i am sending from an HTML form to a Java Servlet (via ajax). I use `crypto-js` in my js to encrypt the password.
When the code reaches the ajax call, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'words' of undefined (aes.js:8)
```

(I already made sure that the key I'm sending is not null)

This is my code:

---

**login.jsp:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
localStorage.setItem('loggedin', false);
</script>
<script src="login.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-    js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/pbkdf2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function convertAndSubmit()
{
    var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
    var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);           
    console.log('salt  '+ salt );
    console.log('iv  '+ iv );
    var key128Bits100Iterations = CryptoJS.PBKDF2('1234567890987654', salt,         { keySize: 256/32, iterations: 100 });
    console.log( 'key128Bits100Iterations '+ key128Bits100Iterations);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt($("#pwd").val(), key128Bits100Iterations, { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7  }).toString();
    checkLogin(encrypted, randkey, salt, iv);
}
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

<div class="container">
  <div id="login-form">
    <h3>Login</h3>

    <fieldset>
      <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="get" name="login">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required value="Email"      onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Email'" onFocus="if(this.value=='Email')this.value='' ">
        <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" required value="Password" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Password'" onFocus="if(this.value=='Password')this.value='' "> 
        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="login" onclick="javascript:convertAndSubmit()">
      </form>
    </fieldset>

  </div> <!-- end login-form -->
</div>
<div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**login.js:**

```
function ajaxLogin(credentials) {
    var retData = null;
    $.ajax({ //this is where the code generates the error
        async: false,
        type: 'GET',
        data: credentials,
        url: "http://localhost:8080/AtlasServices/Login",
        success: function(data) {
            retData = data;
        }
    });
    return retData;
}

function checkLogin(encrypted, key, s, i) {
    var credentials = {
        email: $("#email").val(),
        pass: encrypted,
        key: key,
        salt: s,
        iv: i
    };

    var res = window.ajaxLogin(credentials);
    if (res["userlogged"] !== "true") {
        alert("Failed to log in");
        $("#email").val("");
        $("#pwd").val("");
        localStorage.setItem('loggedin', false);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('loggedin', true);
        window.location = "http://localhost:8080/AtlasServices/main.html";
    }
}
```

---

I was searching for a long time for a solution...will really love some help, thanks:)

Comment: I don't see how it would be possible for that error to appear. The only thing that I see is that you should have used `key128Bits100Iterations` instead of `randkey`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(..)` creates `WordArray` object.

**From your code :**

```
var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
```

This means `salt` and `iv` is an object not a string.

You are able to log `salt` and `iv` as encoded because `console.log` calls  `toString` internally from `salt` and `iv` which `encodes` the `WordArray`

**All you need to do is encode these explicitly:**

```
checkLogin(encrypted, randkey, salt.toString(), iv.toString());
```

**Note:** The error you've got is related with the `JQuery`; while building url parameters `JQuery` reads all `objects`, `sub-objects`, `arrays` and **functions** etc... , When you send `WordArray` as an object jQuery tries to call it's functions to fetch return value into the url parameter.

In your case it is calling the `concat` function with an undefined parameters, which leads to the error you get. You can simply reproduce this error by calling `$.param(salt)` (or for `iv`).